# Django Custom Admin Block For center of admin

Tags: python, html, django, django-admin

So I am overriding change_form.html to add some features to my admin page. Everything is working fine. I am currently using the "after_field_sets" block, but I want to put the content from this page in the center of my field_sets, not after them.

I can put the new content above and below the field sets, but I cannot figure out what block to use to put them in the middle of the field sets.

A list of all the blocks are [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html).

Can anyone help me figure out how to get my new content into the center of the admin page?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the code referenced by the link you posted. I get to the conclusion that, the block you're looking for do not exists. There is a block named `content` but it contains more that just "main content". But this is not the end of the world, you still can edit the template ir order to "make some space" for your content. And very important, remember you can edit `css` and `js` files too.